# How to disabled password authentication for specific users in SSHD

Tags: security, svn, authentication, ssh

I have read several posts regarding restricting ALL users to Key authentication ONLY, however I want to force only a single user (svn) onto Key auth only, the rest can be key or password.

I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241197/how-to-disable-password-authentication-for-every-users-except-several, however it seems the "match user" part of sshd_config is part of openssh-5.1. I am running CentOS 5.6 and only have OpenSSH 4.3. I have the following repos available at the moment.

```
$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
repo id                            repo name                                                                         status
base                               CentOS-5 - Base                                                                   enabled:  3,535
epel                               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                    enabled:  6,510
extras                             CentOS-5 - Extras                                                                 enabled:    299
ius                                IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                            enabled:    218
rpmforge                           RHEL 5 - RPMforge.net - dag                                                       enabled: 10,636
updates                            CentOS-5 - Updates                                                                enabled:    720
repolist: 21,918
```

I mainly use epel, rpmforge is used to the latest version (1.6) of subversion.

Is there any way to achieve this with my current setup? I don't want to restrict the server to keys only because if I lose my key I lose my server ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the Parameter `PermitEmptyPasswords no` in your `sshd` configuration, and delete the passwords for some users, to force ssh key authentication for them.

Comment: That seems to work well. I guess I just have to trust other users that SSH in not to `su svn`. Is there an easy way to stop that (but maybe still allow `sudo su svn`?)

Comment: You could limit the usage of "su" to a specific group. You should have a look at `/etc/pam.d/su` there you will find this line: `# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.`

Comment: That works REALLY well - thank you!

I have also configured scponlyc on the box as well so some users can be root jailed.

Answer (score 14):

Add a Match block to your sshd_config file. Something like this:

```
Match Group SSH_Key_Only_Users
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Or if it's truly one user

```
Match User Bad_User
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

See `man sshd_config` for more details on what you can match and what restrictions you can put in it.

Comment: That was the suggesting in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241197/how-to-disable-password-authentication-for-every-users-except-several - however it required OpenSSH 5.1 and I'm running 4.3 (I'd rather not upgrade to a version which isn't officially supported by CentOS 5.6).

I checked `man sshd_config` and couldn't see any mention of `Match`. I agree, though, that if I were on 5.1 then this would be the answer (as it is in the other post), however I dont believe it will work in 4.3.

Comment: My apologies, didn't realize CentOS was using such an ancient version of SSHd. OpenSSH 4.3 is from Feb 1, 2006; what the heck are they still using that for?

Comment: Not sure, but I assume it still receives security updates?! The full release is:
`openssh.x86_64   4.3p2-72.el5_6.3`

Interestingly, according to the following URL EL6 should be up to OpenSSH 5.3 now...
https://github.com/repoforge/rpms/blob/master/specs/openssh/openssh.spec

My server reports:
`$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.6 (Final)`

It's at times like this when I appreciate the simplicity of OS's like Windows and, to some extent, OS X too. You don't have to faff about with all this dependency malarkey ;)

Answer (score 2):

I just learned the hard way that CentOS 5 (with latest updates as of today) does not support the *Match* command by locking myself out of a remote server.  Fun times.

So be warned if you try add the *Match* command to CE5 and you do *service sshd restart* it won't and as soon as you close your sshd client you are locked out until you can log back in via console to delete those 2 lines.

Comment: Apologies, "(..) it won't (..)" what exactly? It won't restart? It won't add?
Are you aware if the _existing_ sessions be dropped on the restart please and thanks?